# GDI и объединение регионов

Tags: winapi, оптимизация, производительность, gdi

Имеем окно, его контекст и контекст устройства в памяти (совместимый контекст в качестве бэк буфера). В большинстве случаев нам удобнее не создавать дополнительные окна для мелких элементов, а рисовать все в рамках одного контекста.

Допустим нам нужно прорисовать небольшой участок слева сверху, но в то же время такой  же небольшой участок справа снизу. Мы рисуем в буфере оба участка после которых идут вызовы `InvalidateRect` для отображения изменений.

Далее происходит стандартная цепочка

```
WindowCallback > WM_PAINT > BeginPaint
```

В `WM_PAINT` мы блиттим (`BitBlt`) из буфера в основной DC.

В подобной ситуации при втором вызове `InvalidateRect` новый регион автоматически объединяется со старым и `BeginPaint` перерисовывает практически все окно полностью.

> **MSDN:** При установке нескольких областей производится их объединение и
>   обработка одним WM_PAINT

[image: Drawing]
*Откройте изображение в новой вкладке для увеличения*

Исходя из этого вопрос,- можно ли как-то **оптимизировать** этот процесс чтобы ограничить "дорогостоящее" рисование лишь изначальными небольшими участками не отрисовывая окно "целиком", или любым другим образом?

Comment: Попробуйте вызывать `UpdateWindow` после `InvalidateRect` - по идее в этом случае форсится отправка сообщения `WM_PAINT` (если верить тексту в конце этой статьи [Invalidating the Client Area](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/gdi/invalidating-the-client-area))

Comment: Поможет ли в данном случае установка [SetClipRgn](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-selectcliprgn) (полученного объединением нужных кусочков)?

Comment: `UpdateWindow` просто посылает сообщение `WM_PAINT` непосредственно в оконную процедуру в обход очереди сообщений приложения. Не уверен, но клиппинг по большому счету визуальный эффект.

Comment: @A-off, "UpdateWindow просто посылает сообщение WM_PAINT непосредственно в оконную процедуру в обход очереди сообщений приложения" - почитал про UpdateWindow, таки да - она вызывает оконную процедуру непосредственно, но нам это и нужно - оконная процедура будет вызвана с маленьким регионом, и будет обновлен только он, а не большой регион.

Comment: Это так и в целом решает поставленную задачу. Спасибо!
Немного избыточно, но вполне неплохой рабочий вариант, почти не уступает в скорости "обходному" пути, но главное универсален и применим практически в любой ситуации.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

В конечном счете решил вопрос рисованием в обход `WM_PAINT`, благо конкретно этот частный случай позволяет это сделать. Не пришлось добавлять лишний код в обработчик (что тоже было бы вариантом, но тут это лишнее).

В большинстве же случаев, думаю решение от *insolor* с `UpdateWindow` будет лучше.

Comment: Может быть добавите какой-то пример кода?